# pip won't execute from Windows command line

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

I have  pip.exe in the  Python27 directory I'm trying to check if it is installed well by giving the command:

```
C:\Python27>pip
```

Every time I do so I get the following error message:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create a process using `"C:\Python34\python.exe" "C:\Python27\pip.exe" `
```

I have changed the PATH in the environment variables so there is NO mention of Python34.

Why won’t it show pip is installed? Thanks for help.

I have followed advice about changing the PATH by editing the environment variables etc... For some reason it always tries to follow a path via Python34 which is not there! Is that why it gives the error?

I can get Python to execute with the same approach but never pip.
I want to install Django.

Comment: The error message suggests that the `pip.exe` that you have here is a 3.4 version. If your Python 2.7 is >= 2.7.9, pip should be used as `python -m pip`. If it is an older version, you should install a fresh pip following [How do I install pip on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: As @SergeBallesta mentioned, you have the wrong pip.exe (its embedded shebang is for 3.4). It's also in the wrong directory. It should be in `C:\Python27\Scripts`. Delete `C:\Python27\pip.exe` and run `C:\python27\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`.